# Regex for IP capture or hostname

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex for `IP` capture or `hostname`, and ignore anything after `#`

**DATA**

```
192.168.0.41 #obs
SRVNET #obs
192.168.0.4 #obs
```

**REGEX**

```
^(([1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])).){3}([1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]|[a-z]))$
```

Comment: go to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and check your regex. it's easy

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/kFJlBa/1

Comment: What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: the space between the captured values

Comment: Per your sample data, `\S+(?=\s*#obs)` https://regex101.com/r/HzCpf6/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus \S+(?=\s*#) perfect, thanks!!

Comment: regex like `^((\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})|([A-Z\d]{1,20}))` will match IP and hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first part of the pattern from the comments you are matching `[^#]+` which is a negated character class and will also match a space.

As you don't want to match spaces, you could add `\s` to it to not match whitespace characters.

The whole match is wrapped in group 1, but as that is the only match you might make it non capturing `(?:`

Note that you have to escape the dot to match it literally and that `[1]` is the same as just 1.

```
^(?:[^#\s]+)|^((1?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.){3}(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$
       ^^       ^^                                ^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/73yurl/1)